# SD card initialize and fails when date changed

Tags: atmega328, sd-card

i am making a project using Arduino Uno that display data on 7 seg display which stored in SD card as day by day. when i make power ON to device then SD card initialization done & data shows correct as per date. Then after when i change the date SD card failed i.e. "show error opening database.txt" .

How can i overcome with this?

" When debugging my SD Card I had a software error that would put the
card into a state that required the microSD card to be powered down and then
powered up to work. It would work until the software error and then not
work again until the power was cycled. "

Comment: what software error?